# how to compare attribute values including comparison operators in C#

Tags: c#, xml, string

I am comparing two XML nodes which includes numeric values with comparison operators as shown below

```
<rule id="rule1" subject="user1" age="60" permission="granted"/>
<rule id="rule2" subject="user1" age=">=50" permission="denied"/>
```

This is a very simple example where the rule1 states that if the subject is user1 then the permission is granted if his age is 60 whereas the rule2 states that permission is denied for user1 if age is 50 or greater than 50. So it mean these rules are contradictory.

My question is that how could I compare the age attribute which is including numeric values and comparison operators. In the above example I conclude that both the rules have contradictory values.

I am using C# to compare these attribute values.

Comment: You cant use an unescaped `>` in an attribute value - even the parser here on SO is indicating that

Comment: What is the logic of comparison?

Comment: This is just an example. I need to handle these values. whether in XML or in any other form. I know we need to use ;&gt for > in attribute value

Comment: Logic of comparison is that I want to check whether both the rules are contradictory or not. As in this example rule1 grants access for a user if the age is 60 whereas rule2 denies access if the age is 50 or above. It mean a person 60 year old has no access rights. So both these rules are contradictory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a syntax tree from xml and use the tree to evaluate the conditions. As for how to evaluate comparison-based rule, you can write your own class like:

```
public enum BinaryOperator
{
  LessThenOrEqual,
  LessThen,
  Equal,
  GreaterThen,
  GreaterThenOrEqual
}

public class BinaryOperatorEvaluator
{
  public BinaryOperatorEvaluator(BinaryOperator op)
  {
    Operator = op;
  }

  public BinaryOperator Operator { get; private set; }

  public bool Evaluate(IComparable x, IComparable y)
  {
    switch (Operator)
    {
      case BinaryOperator.Equal:
        return x.CompareTo(y) == 0;
      case BinaryOperator.GreaterThen:
        return x.CompareTo(y) > 0;
      case BinaryOperator.GreaterThenOrEqual:
        return x.CompareTo(y) >= 0;
      case BinaryOperator.LessThen:
        return x.CompareTo(y) < 0;
      case BinaryOperator.LessThenOrEqual:
        return x.CompareTo(y) <= 0;
      default:
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }

  public static BinaryOperatorEvaluator FromExpression(string expression, out int value)
  {
    var regexValidTerm = new Regex("^(?<operator>(<=|=|>=|<|>)?)(?<numeric>([0-9]+))$");
    var match = regexValidTerm.Match(expression);
    if (!match.Success)
    {
      throw new ArgumentException("Not a valid expression.", "expression");
    }
    var opValue = match.Groups["operator"].Value;
    var op = BinaryOperator.Equal;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(opValue))
    {
      switch(opValue)
      {
        case "<=":
          op = BinaryOperator.LessThenOrEqual;
          break;
        case "=":
          op = BinaryOperator.Equal;
          break;
        case ">=":
          op = BinaryOperator.GreaterThenOrEqual;
          break;
        case "<":
          op = BinaryOperator.LessThen;
          break;
        case ">":
          op = BinaryOperator.LessThenOrEqual;
          break;
        default:
          throw new NotImplementedException();
      }
    }

    value = int.Parse(match.Groups["numeric"].Value);

    return new BinaryOperatorEvaluator(op);
  }
}


int number;
var bo = BinaryOperatorEvaluator.FromExpression("<=15", out number);
// false
var foo = bo.Evaluate(16, number);
// true
foo = bo.Evaluate(15, number);
// also true
foo = bo.Evaluate(14, number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `runat="server"` inside your tags, then access the attribute with `rule1.Attributes["age"]` within c# code. And overload operator for comparison if its logic requires this.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider doing this in code behind, makes it a heck lot easier.

```
    if(age > 50)
permission = "denied";
else if(age == 60)
permission = "granted";
```